# Apache beam with SqlTransform in direct runner

Tags: python, sql, apache-beam

I have the following code to run sql transformations in apache beam in direct runner on windows.

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.transforms.sql import SqlTransform

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    pipe = (
        p
        |'hello' >> beam.Create([('SE',400),('SC',500)])
        |'schema' >> beam.Map(lambda x: beam.Row(
                                                state=x[0],
                                                population=x[1]
                                                ))
    )

    sql = (
        pipe
        |'sql' >> SqlTransform('SELECT state, population FROM PCOLLECTION')
        |'sql print' >> beam.Map(print)
    )
```

And I get the following error:

```
  File "c:\users\XXX\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1306, in send_signal
    raise ValueError("Unsupported signal: {}".format(sig))
ValueError: Unsupported signal: 2
```

I saw on youtube experts saying about Universal Local Runner, but I didn't find how to install it.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I followed the conversation in the mail archive, and the issue in Jira .. looks like no update regarding this one

Comment: yes, not yet....

Comment: Is there already a solution for this? Or a workaround at least? What pipeline could be used locally instead?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is now tracked in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-12501.

I have no issue running your pipeline with source code built from Beam head. But I'm on Mac OS. What version of Beam did you use?

Could you try asking about it to the user@beam.apache.org? This might be an issue specific in the Windows system.

Comment: I am using 2.30.0. I will ask in the beam mailing list. Thanks

Comment: This issue has been migrated to https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/21069